# AJAX auto-suggest combo box

Tags: javascript, ajax, combobox, autocomplete, autosuggest

I’m looking for an AJAX-enabled combo box with the following features:

1. The combo box accepts entries selected from a drop-down as well as free-form text entered by the user (kind of like the text field used to enter tags for StackOverflow questions)
2. The drop-down list contains a limited number (less than 10) of suggestions based on what the user typed so far
3. The suggestions are pulled from a primary list and a secondary list.  The secondary list is consulted if the user’s input cannot be matched to anything in the primary list.  Both lists are generated on demand by my application running on the server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery-ui has an [autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) plugin that offers this functionality.

Comment: If you go to the official site for that plugin, you'll see that the author has deprecated this plugin in favor of the jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin, which is what you **should** be using instead